# Allow boot from external drive in Recovery mode after the disk is erased

Tags: startup, recovery

I have erased my Macbook Pro disk. The network install method failed. So I want to reinstall from USB installer. But I don't have admin account since the whole disk is erased. I need:

1. create admin account in recovery mode
2. Or change the setting to allow boot from external drive

The disk is erased, so there is no way I can go to the normal mode or single user mode.

Thanks!

Comment: If you can boot in recovery mode, you can reinstall macOS. Otherwise, you need another Mac to download an installer and create a USB installer.

Comment: Perhaps a third option would be to copy the USB installer to an internal partition, then boot from the internal drive to reinstall macOS.